# Change XLS page margins when exporting html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, xls

I export an html table using javascript.

I need to change the generated margins of the xls. The default margins are normal type.

Setting the margins in the table does not work.

```
function download_xls() {
var xls=""; 
xls+='<table style="width:100%" margin:"0" border="0" padding="5" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr height="20"px; style="border:0px;" >\
<td style="height:20px; width: 90px; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border- 
bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: 
solid 1px #000000; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text- 
align: left; ">IDENTIFICATION;N</td>\
<td style="height:20px; width: 97px; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border- 
bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: 
solid 1px #000000; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font- 
weight: bold; text-align: left; ">TAG</td>\
<td style="height:20px; width: 99px; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border- 
bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: 
solid 1px #000000; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font- 
weight: bold; text-align: left; "></td>\
<td style="height:20px; width: 27px; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border- 
bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: 
solid 1px #000000; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text- 
align: center; ">REV</td>\
</tr>\
</table>'

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(xls);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'PT.xls';
hiddenElement.click();

}
download_xls();
```

Comment: You might find it helpful to know about PHPExcel (new version called PHPSpreadsheet). It has gazillions of methods you can use to do what you want. To use it locally, you would install a LAMP stack like XAMPP. There is a learning curve (less with PHPExcel, which is deprecated but still works perfectly), but in the end it might save you time. However, you haven't provided much information about how the code will be used, so my suggestion could be irrelevant. For manipulating XLS outside of MSExcel, most mature product is PHPExcel. Next is OpenPyXL in Python. Javascript solns a distant third.